# What is the best datatype for currencies in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, types, currency

I want to store values in a bunch of currencies and I'm not too keen on the imprecise nature of floats. Being able to do math on them directly in queries is also a requirement.

Is Decimal the way to go here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Decimal is the best way to go.

You can still do math within the queries.