# Mysql: money and floats

Tags: mysql

What float do I need to store such sums like these: $1,200,000, $1,000, and $14.56 ? ($ dosn't count; it will be removed)

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248512/what-is-the-best-datatype-for-currencies-in-mysql

Comment: Store an integer number of pennies. If your application needs more precision than that and you're here asking what representation to use, you're not competent to be writing this application.

Answer (score 4):

Don't. Store as an int and multiply/divide by 100. e.g. Store 14.56 as 1456, but /100 when displaying. Floating point for storing currency is just asking for rounding problems.

Comment: So do you think i should store $1,000 as 1000? and then devide it by 100? = 10?

Comment: No, always assume 2 places for cents, i.e. 1000 = 100000 in storage. Of course, if you're dealing with more than just 2 decimal places for cents, i.e. handling fractions of cents (financial industry perhaps) then this technique won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try DECIMAL.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html