# the mysql function sum() is showing unexpected result!

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I use the sum() function for provision in my mysql database, in this case query fetches only 1 result, it is 29.9

So sum(provision) is 29.8 I dont understand why is this happening! it is supposed to stay 29.8!

in another query I use sum() two results with 29.9 and it returns 59.7, but when I calculate it with windows calculator it returns 59.8!

Comment: sounds like a classic floating point rounding issue to me.

Comment: What is the type of the field you are summing?

Comment: @TooCooL See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best datatype for currencies in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248512/what-is-the-best-datatype-for-currencies-in-mysql)

Comment: @ Treffynnon I have problem when I change it to DECIMAL type because it doesnt hold decimal numbers but it rounds the number for example the it changes the 29.9 to 30! and when I try to change it manually in phpmyadmin it gives me this error: 

Note: #1265 Data truncated for column 'provision' at row 1

Comment: @TooCooL Don't enter spaces between the @ and the username like you have above (@ Treffynnon) otherwise StackOverflow doesn't post notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [MySQL `DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html) specified something like:

```
DECIMAL(20,2)
```

See the [man page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html) for more information.